# How can I vectorise this range find over columns in a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Essentially I have an image mask and I want to find the width of the image in each column. Is there a way to vectorise this for speed? I tried to figure out a way with arrayfun but haven't hit on anything yet.

```
r = zeros(1,cols);
for i = 1 : cols
    r(i) = range(find(img(:,i)));
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code does the same as yours in a vectorized manner:

```
imglog = img~=0; %// convert to 0 and 1 values
[~, i1] = max(imglog); %// i1 is the position of the first 1
[~, i2] = max(flipud(imglog)); %// size(img,1)+1-i2 is the position of the last 1
r = size(img,1)+1-i2 - i1;
```

It exploits the fact that the second output of [`max`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/max.html) gives the position of the *first* maximizer (for each column).

Comment: NICE! And indeed faster than my version! :) [cputime evaluation shows your version is 8 times faster than mine!]

Comment: @matheburg Thanks! `cellfun` is neat, but usually slow

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is faster, but `num2cell` + `cellfun` seems to be the only way to vectorize general functions on columns:

```
r = cellfun(@(x)range(find(x)),num2cell(img,1));
```

Answer (score 1):

**[`find`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/find.html)** + **[`unique`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/unique.html)** approach -

```
[row1,col1]  = find(img);
[~,start1] = unique(col1,'first');
[~,stop1] = unique(col1);
r = row1(stop1) - row1(start1);
```

Comment: I had no choice but this one! You stole the `max` :) That has to be faster! You had my +1 already because of that!